# Java: cross-platform .flv playback

Tags: java, ffmpeg, flv, flvplayback

I'm looking for a way to playback .flv files using java. This means I will need a ffmpeg lib that is cross-platform. I've been toying with jmf and fobs4jmf, but I cannot playback in linux because I need a native library (maybe fobs4jmf.so?).

Is there any java lib that allows me to playback .flv besides fobs4jmf? Or fobs4jmf can be used in linux, mac, etc? A pure-java lib would be perfect!

Edit: The player will be deployed as a java web start app (targetting jre6).

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably not reading your question correctly, but I don't understand what you have against fobs4jmf. It seems to support Mac and Linux fine, see http://fobs.sourceforge.net/f4jmf_first.html

Answer (score 1):

i would use a blatant shortcut.  use an embedded browser and have it play the file using the browser's flash plugin.

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#browser

heres how to embed a browser in your app, and just deliver it content through a really simple embedded web server.  im sure you can just pickup a flash app that plays flv's no problem with the help of google.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want a go with javafx in this: http://java.dzone.com/news/video-getting-started-with-jav

Answer (score 1):

[Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) works on Linux, Mac and Windows.  I think it'll do the trick.